# Append iframe differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I appended the iframe as shown below, easily.

```
$("p").append("<iframe src='http://www.site.com'></iframe>");
```

But search bots also see this url and go to the url. What I want to do is to make the same append differently. If it was in php, I can do that with

```
$part1 = "<iframe src='http://www.site";
$part2 = ".com'></iframe>";

echo $part1$part2;
```

But how can I achieve the same using jquery?

Comment: I don't think the PHP way makes any difference. In the end, the browser sees is the resulting HTML, and there will be no trace that you built the code out of two strings. And bots normally don't execute Javascript, or do they now?

Comment: I think the OP means a bot will see that domain in the source, and follow it as if it was a link.

Comment: @seanxe: Ah ok...makes sense then. user: Why don't you simply cracreatey two strings as well then and concatenate them?

Comment: php is server based. If I use that php code above, it will be seen as same as full iframe url. But with jquery its client based and if you look at source it wont be seen as full iframe url.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Then why don't you do it? I'm confused...

Comment: I am not good at jquery and wanted it in jquery.

Comment: There is no way to do this with jQuery. Just use normal string concatenation in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below :

```
var part1 = "<iframe src='http://www.site"; 
var part2 = ".com'></iframe>"; 
$("p").append(part1+part2);
```

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't make any difference how you genereate the iframe because as @felix-kling said it displays the content as HTML in the end and, if the script executes scripts, like it seems to be doing for you if you are already using jQuery to generate the iframe. The next best thing to do is to try and block the script being run.

This can be done in a number of ways,

Put your Script in an external js file in a directory blocked by robots.txt file or even better use a .htaccess file to block external sites from accessing the js files in that directory.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteRule .*\.(js)$ - [F]
```

Comment: I think @seanxe has a point. Some bots will simply parse the source of the page for URLs (no matter where they appear).

Comment: @felix-kling that's why I suggested the .htaccess solution, that would be the server stopping requests directly to the js file without the correct referrer of the site that owns it. So the bot should not be able to read the file, unless it is also submitting the correct referrer as well.

Comment: Wouldn't that also match `http://linkgrabber.com?siteToPester=www.mysite.com/js.js`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").append("<iframe src='http://www.s"+"ite.com'></iframe>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to build up the domain parts:

```
var domain = [];
domain.push('http://', 'www', 'site', '.com');
$('p').append('<iframe src="', domain.join(''), '"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").append($('<iframe />', { 'src' : 'http://www.site.com' }));
```

Comment: I think the point is to split the URL into pieces so that it is not recognized as URL.